# How to create a spherical angular gradient around y-axis using Lua in Filter Forge?

Tags: filter, lua, graphics, scripting, forge

I am working on a Spherical Map Script that generates a linear gradient along the y-axis and an angular gradient around the y-axis in the green and red channels, respectively. I have been unable to find any documentation suited to this online, but have experimented using examples in Javascript and C#. The linear gradient has worked out fine, but the angular gradient (one describing a 360 degree arc around the y-axis) continues to elude me.

My working script is as follows.

```
-- 3d sphere 
    -- produces rgb gradudient mapped to a 3d sphere, but not correctly. 
    -- this is basically missing an angle gradient around the y-axis...
function prepare()
    -- tilt & rotation precalc
    toRad = 180/math.pi
    -- toCir = 360/math.p -- may or may not work for circumference...

    radius = get_slider_input(RADIUS)

    angle = get_angle_input(ROTATION)/toRad
    cosa = math.cos(angle)
    sina = math.sin(angle)

    tilt = get_angle_input(TILT)/toRad
    cosa2 = math.cos(tilt)
    sina2 = math.sin(tilt)
end;


function get_sample(x, y)
    local r, g, b, a = get_sample_map(x, y, SOURCE)
    -- color gradient example
    --  local r = x
    --  local g = y
    --  local b = (x + y) / 2
    --  local a = 1
    -- spherical mapping formulae (polar to cartesian, apparently)
    --  local x = x * math.pi -- * aspect 
    --  local y = y * math.pi
    --  local nx = math.cos(x) * math.sin(y) 
    --  local ny = math.sin(x) * math.sin(y) 
    --  local nz = math.cos(y) 
    -- cartesian to polar (reference)
    --  example 1
    --  r = math.sqrt(((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z))) 
    --  long = math.acos(x / math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y))) * (y < 0 ? -1 : 1) 
    --  lat = math.acos(z / radius) * (z < 0 ? -1 : 1) 
    --  example 2
    --      r = math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z)) 
    --      long = math.acos(x / math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y))) * (y < 0 ? -1 : 1) 
    --  lat = math.acos(z / r) 
            -- equations cannot accept boolean comparison
            -- boolean syntax may not be valid in lua
   
    -- image generation
    -- shift origin to center and set radius limits
    local px = (x*2.0) - 1.0
    local py = (y*2.0) - 1.0
    px = px/radius
    py = py/radius
    local len = math.sqrt((px*px)+(py*py))
    if len > 1.0 then return 0,0,0,0 end

    local z = -math.sqrt(1.0 - ((px*px)+(py*py)))

    -- cartesian to polar
        -- r = math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z))
        -- lat = math.acos(z / r)
        -- long = math.acos(x / math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y))) * (y < 0) ? -1 : 1) 

    -- apply rotaqtion and tilt (order is important)
    local tz = (cosa2 * z) - (sina2 * py) 
    local ty = (sina2 * z) + (cosa2 * py) -- gradient along y-axis is correct
    z = tz 
    py = ty

    local tx = (cosa * px) - (sina * z) -- gradient needs to go around y-axis
    local tz = (sina * px) + (cosa * z)
    px = tx
    z = tz

        -- r = math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z)) 
        -- lat = math.acos(z / r) -- invalid z for this; what is correct source?
        -- long = math.acos(x / math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y))) -- map -1 : 1 needed
        -- long = (sina * px) + (cosa * z) -- ok;  2 full rotations

    -- return r, g, b, a
    -- return px,py,z,a 
    return px/2+.5,py/2+.5,z/2+.5,a 
    -- return px/2+.5,px/2+.5,px/2+.5,a 
    -- return long,long,long,a 
    -- return px/2+.5,py/2+.5,long,a 
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to construct a spherical angular gradient from the hemispherical axis gradients I started with, by using three as the RBG channels in an RBG to HSL conversion. I've used this to map textures to spheres in Filter Forge in map scripts like [this](https://github.com/eyeofparadox/ff_lua_scripts/blob/main/ff_api_3d_perlin_sphere_map_v.1.0.1.lua).

I thought I'd share the solution for anyone who's followed my question here.